# Magento Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototype

I have s script that calls a third party payment feature, but one line of code conflicts with Magento Prototy:

```
<script>
pay.configure('pub_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
</script>
```

I get this error in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: pay is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (prototype.js:612), <anonymous>:3:1)
at prototype.js:612
at prototype.js:865
at prototype.js:825
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Array.each (prototype.js:824)
at Array.collect (prototype.js:864)
at String.evalScripts (prototype.js:612)
at Function.<anonymous> (prototype.js:391)
at prototype.js:416
```

I'm not familiar with this function, any ideas to how to define/call it.

Comment: Add relevant JS having `pay` variable defined in it.

Comment: tried a simple var declaration of pay but its not working

Answer (score 0):

The error is most probably due to the fact that the script are not loaded in the good order. The script where pay is defined is most probably loaded after the script that use it.

Comment: Tried that also, but script works fine outside Magento.

Comment: with that few information, it is all the help I can give. Sorry. Follow @rohan guidelines to get more help.